# Java 8 non-blocking read has race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, java-8, nonblocking

now this problem is bugging me for a while.

In a working application that i work on, i use SocketChannel in non-blocking mode to communicate with embedded devices.
Now i receive sporadically corrupted data. 
On some PCs it does not happen, now it happens on mine.
But when I change too much in the program, the problem disappears.

So much might have effects. The timing, the network interface hardware, win7, the java version, the company firewall, ...

The data reading boils down to this code:

```
byteBuffer.compact();
socketChannel.read(byteBuffer); // <<< problem here ?
byteBuffer.flip();
if( byteBuffer.hasRemaining() ){
    handleData( byteBuffer );
}
```

This is run in the same thread as the writing, when the selector wakes up and the interest op OP_READ is set.

This code is the only place where byteBuffer is referenced. socketChannel is used only from the same thread when writing.

I instrumented the code, so i can printout the content of the last few read() calls, when the error happens. At the same time I analyze the network traffic on Wireshark. I added lots of asserts to check the bytebuffer integrity.

In Wireshark, the received stream looks good. No DUP-ACK or something else suspicious. The last read() calls match exactly with the data in Wireshark.

In Wireshark, i see many small TCP frames receiving with 90 bytes of payload data in intervals like 10ms arriving. Normally the Java thread reads the data as well all 10ms when it is just arrived.

When it comes to the problem, the Java thread is a bit delay, as the reading happens after 300ms, and the read returns with like ~3000 bytes which is plausible. But the data is corrupted.

The data looks like, if it was copied into the buffer and concurrently received data has overwritten the first data.

Now I don't know how to proceed. I cannot create a small example, as this only rarely happens and I don't know the exact condition which is needed.

Can someone give a hint?

How can I prove, it is the Java lib or not?

What conditions may be important to look at, too?

thanks
Frank

29-June-2015:

Now i was able to build a example for reproduction.

There is one [Sender](https://gist.github.com/keinfarbton/a168ee30eb831996b149) and a [Receiver](https://gist.github.com/keinfarbton/04b62abd4f23190c33ff) program.

The Sender is using blocking IO, first waiting for a connection, then sending 90 byte blocks every 2ms. The first 4 byte are a running counter, the remaining is not set. The Sender uses setNoTcpDelay(true).

The Receiver is using non-blocking IO. First it connects to the Sender, then it read the channel whenever the selection key is ready for it. Sometime, the read loop does a Thread.sleep(300).

If they run on the same PC over the loopback, this works for me all the time. If I put the Sender onto another PC, directly connected over LAN, it triggers the error. Checking with Wireshark, the traffic and the data sent looks good.

To run, first start the Sender on one PC, then (after editing the hostaddress) start the Receiver.

As long as it works, it prints a line about every 2 seconds. If it fails, it prints information about the last 5 read() calls.

What i found to be the trigger:

1. The sender has configured setNoTcpDelay(true)
2. The receiver has sometimes a Thread.sleep(300) before doing the read().

thanks
Frank

Comment: While it is possible that there is a bug in Java, it is extremely unlikely ... given the vast number of other Java 8 programmers who are (apparently) not experiencing this kind of problem.  It is more likely to be a bug in your code.  What to do?  Well if your code is too difficult to reduce to an MCVE, and too large to show us, then your best bet is to get a colleague to help you.

Comment: If the code is all executing on one thread, then it is unlikely to be a "race condition" in the normal sense.  (I don't know if that helps ...)

Comment: From what you mention - there might be a problem - in the way you are consuming the data. This is just a guess though. For some reason not explained by what you mentioned - when the java thread that reads the data gets scheduled after 300ms, you've so many 90 bytes packets received back to back. If you were assuming to read them in chunks of 90 bytes, be explicit to read in 90 bytes. And then consume more - when they are more than 90 bytes. I am not aware of the exact APIs, but may be this should point in some direction?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you reading into `buf` instead of `byteBuffer`? Seriously, how are we supposed to help you without knowing what you are really doing with the buffer? I.e. what does `handleData( byteBuffer )` do?

Comment: *But when I change too much in the program, the problem disappears.* this is about as ambiguous and inspecific as you can get.

Comment: @Holger: in the code there was a typo. Should have been socketChannel.read(byteBuffer); My whole analysis reduces all to the read() call. the bytebuffer pos is 0, limit at capacity (100k), for all cases read() was called and the problem occurred afterwards. 

I tried to fill the buffer with zeros before calling read().
I tried to read in smaller chunks (setting limit) or with smaller buffers.
I collect data for the last 5 calls, so i can print it in case of the error.
I have the case, when I allocate a byte array before calling the read(), the problem might disappear.

Comment: @StephenC the reading/writing is done in a single thread, but other threads in the program exist, that have as well selectors. And the data is obviously delivered asynchronously. So if i ask for a race condition in SocketChannel.read() it is possible even if i access it from a single thread only.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I wanted to say, that if i add e.g. a buffer allocation like new byte[200] (to collect debug data) before the read(), the problem might disappear.

Comment: looks like you are reusing the byteBuffer, and the buffer is inadvertently shared among different readers/writers. Try create a new buffer for each read, and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: why are you calling `compact()`? which might cause the issue you are seeing if there was data in the buffer previously

Comment: @bayou.io as I said "This code is the only place where byteBuffer is referenced.". handleData really does only copy out. By testing for the error, i have verified, in this case, the buffer passed to read() has the position at zero and the limit at 100k.

Comment: @dkatzel in my case where the problem happens, the handleData consumes always all packets, because they are only 90 bytes long. But they could be longer, e.g. 20k. In such a case the read() would return with only a partial packet and handleData would not process it. For this case I need compact(). But as already said, the read() before the problem is trigger have only 90 bytes each, they are consumed completely and then the block with wrong data is read, while Wireshark shows the correct trace.

Comment: does `handleData()` change buffer position even when "it would not process it"?

Comment: @bayou.io this does not happen in the last 5 actions before the problem occurs. I am sure because i added code to test this. But if this would be the case, it does query the length with absolute bulk (getInt(index) and compared to remaining()) and either goes out or starts processing.

Comment: Maybe a flip/reset/rewind issue. Maybe the issue disappears when using a new ByteBuffer for every communication.

Comment: Data is not delivered asynchronously in non-blocking mode. You can't have a 'race condition' in a single thread. Code should be posted here, not via links. Read loops should *never* sleep. All you have to do is remove it. This inspires zero confidence in the rest of your code. However I've taken the additional trouble, which should have been unnecessary, to chase your link and review it: see below.

Comment: @JoopEggen no, why do you think this? When the error disappear, when i toggle the use of "thread.sleep" and/or "setTcpNoDelay", why should it be related to the buffer?

Comment: @EJP i added the Thread.sleep to simulated the real behavior of my bigger application. In real live it can happen, that the thread is block by something, e.g. doing work, or other threads are executed, or another process is consuming lots of CPU. However, this *should* not influence the data correctness. A race condition, can happen, if you have the scope bigger as your application. It can happen between the "single thread" and the IRQ of the network interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out to be a driver problem, at least it seems so.

I used the USB to Ethernet adapater "D-Link E-DUB100 Rev **A**".
Because of wireshark showing the correct data, i thought to eliminate the hardware a possible failure cause.
But meanwhile i tried "D-Link E-DUB100 Rev **C1**" and the problem disappeared.
So I assume it is a problem in the delivered drivers from D-Link for Rev A. And with Rev C1 it might use a system driver that does not have this problem.

thx for all taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
        buf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
```

This is the default. Remove this.

```
        buf.clear();
```

The buffer is already empty, because you just allocated it. Remove this.

```
        buf.limit(0);
```

The limit is already zero after the clear() and also after the initial allocation. Remove this.

```
        while( true ) {
```

There should be a select() call here.

```
            Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            // ...
            if( key == keyData && key.isConnectable() ) {
                    ch.finishConnect();
```

This method can return false. You're not handling that case.

```
            // ...
            if( key == keyData && key.isReadable() ) {

                    // ...
                    readPos += ch.read(buf);
```

Completely incorrect. You are entirely overlooking the case where `read()` returns -1, meaning the peer has disconnected. In this case you must close the channel.

```
            // without this Thread.sleep, it would not trigger the error
```

So? Hasn't the penny dropped? *Remove the sleep.* It is completely and utterly pointless. The `select()` will block until data arrives. It doesn't need your help. This sleep is literally a waste of time.

```
            if( rnd.nextInt(20) == 0 ) {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
```

Remove this.

```
            selector.select();
```

This should be at the top of the loop, not the bottom.

Comment: you know this is a minimal example? The read() -> -1 case is irrelevant. the byte order/clear/limit might be redundant, still it is not wrong. The Thread.sleep *is* the important point here. As I want to trigger a problem seen in a more complex program. I know it is not needed here. if the select is in the end, the first iteration will have an empty selectedkey set.

Comment: stackoverflow did not let me paste in the code. Hence I posted via link.

Comment: From javadoc of ByteBuffer.allocate: "The new buffer's position will be zero, its limit will be its capacity". This means the limit(0) call *is* needed.